# ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Invalid value for property [api_endpoint_overrides/run]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I was trying to automate a CI/CD pipeline with a trigger. I'm stuck here as it's failing with an error saying

```js
 Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Invalid value for property [api_endpoint_overrides/run]:
 The endpoint_overrides property must be an absolute URI beginning with 
 http:// or https:// and ending with a trailing '/'. [https://us-central1 - run.googleapis.com/] 
 is not a valid endpoint override.
```

`cloudbuild.yaml`

```js
 steps:
 # Build the container image
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app2:$COMMIT_SHA', '.']
 # Push the container image to Container Registry
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app2:$COMMIT_SHA']
 # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
 - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
   entrypoint: gcloud
   args:
   - 'run'
   - 'deploy'
   - 'app2'
   - '--image'
   - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app2:$COMMIT_SHA'
   - '--region'
   - 'us-central1 '
 images:
 - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app2:$COMMIT_SHA'
 options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

Comment: Have you seen this post on [github](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun/issues/297#issuecomment-1027290608)?

Comment: You appear to have an extraneous space in the region name.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same error in Google Cloud. In my case the root cause was also the region name. I'm not sure why my region name "us-central1" was wrong but I replaced it with "europe-west1" which worked out in the end.